# How to simplify this code where a variable is declared after an user input in c++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, scope

I wrote the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public : float lgth;
    public : void getLgth() { cin >> lgth;}
};

class Square : public Shape {
    public : float calcArea() { return lgth * lgth; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public : float calcArea() { return 3.14 * lgth * lgth; }
};

int main() {
    char shape_type;

    cout <<"Shape Type (c/s) ? ";
    cin >> shape_type;
    if (shape_type == 'c') {
      Circle my_shape;
      cout << "Shape Length ? ";
      my_shape.getLgth();
      cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << endl;
    }
    else if (shape_type == 's') {
      Square my_shape;
      cout << "Shape Length ? ";
      my_shape.getLgth();
      cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As the type of shape is not known at the beginning of the execution (it is asked to user), the variable `my_shape` is declared in an `if then else` statement. After this variable is only known in this scope (I understand this point). So, this part of code :

```
  cout << "Shape Length ? ";
  my_shape.getLgth();
  cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << endl;
```

must be repeated twice in this example.(But more if many shape classes exist).

I am a beginner in C++ but I supposed it is not the best way to do it. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just keep reading and learning, one chapter at a time, from your C++ textbook. Eventually you'll get to learn about templates and all will become crystal clear. But it is very, very important to follow an organized curriculum for learning the hardest and most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. All attempts to haphazardly jump into advanced topics, before learning the fundamentals, will always end in tears.

Comment: I'll say that there's only three or four duplicate lines here – any "smart" solution you come up with has the chance to be more complicated to read and understand. That might not be worth it! You'll, correctly, say that this is but an example and of course such sections might become longer, and yes, that's true, but the moment you reach that level, you will have mastered other techniques, so that a) the solution will become something you might be able to come up with yourself and b) you realize that there's trade-offs between writing generic-as-possible and clear-as-possible code. Have fun!

Comment: @Sam and Marcus. Thanks for comments and II fully agree with your comments. But simple answer like the Jarod42's one helps a lot to avoid tears and to have fun :)

Comment: Templates seem easy. Until they're not. Without a methodical explanation of what templates ***really are*** there's lots of fun to look forward to. Why doesn't this compile, this template parameter should not even use this `if` statement's code at all? Why doesn't this link, my template is defined right here, in this `.cpp` file I'm definitely compiling and linking? And many, many more, as witnessed simply by visiting Stackoverflow's graveyard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution is to create the object dynamically after you know what type you want to use, and use virtual methods to handle common interactions on  the different types, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public :
        float lgth;
        virtual ~Shape() = default;
        void getLgth() { cin >> lgth; }
        virtual float calcArea() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return lgth * lgth; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return 3.14 * lgth * lgth; }
};

int main() {
    char shape_type;
    Shape* my_shape;

    cout << "Shape Type (c/s) ? ";
    cin >> shape_type;

    if (shape_type == 'c') {
        my_shape = new Circle;
    }
    else if (shape_type == 's') {
        my_shape = new Square;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unknown type!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Shape Length ? ";
    my_shape->getLgth();
    cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape->calcArea() << endl;

    delete my_shape;

    return 0;
}
```

Note, in modern C++, you should use smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr`, instead of using `new`/`delete` directly, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public :
        float lgth;
        virtual ~Shape() = default;
        void getLgth() { cin >> lgth; }
        virtual float calcArea() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return lgth * lgth; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public :
        float calcArea() override { return 3.14 * lgth * lgth; }
};

int main() {
    char shape_type;
    unique_ptr<Shape> my_shape;

    cout << "Shape Type (c/s) ? ";
    cin >> shape_type;

    if (shape_type == 'c') {
        my_shape = make_unique<Circle>();
    }
    else if (shape_type == 's') {
        my_shape = make_unique<Square>();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unknown type!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Shape Length ? ";
    my_shape->getLgth();
    cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape->calcArea() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 good catch. I added it.

Answer (score 2):

With template, you might factorize code:

```
template <typename TShape>
// requires(std::derived_from<TShape, Shape>) // C++20 constraint
void do_job()
{
    TShape my_shape;
    std::cout << "Shape Length ?";
    my_shape.getLgth();
    std::cout << "Shape Area : " << my_shape.calcArea() << std::endl;
}
```

And in your `main`:

```
if (shape_type == 'c') {
    do_job<Circle>();
} else if (shape_type == 's') {
    do_job<Square>();
}
```

or with more types

```
switch (shape_type) {
    case 'c': do_job<Circle>(); break;
    case 's': do_job<Square>(); break;
// ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MEEe4P55G)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helps me to have fun and to avoid tears :) (See my comment in the question to understand). I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: This is definitely not the best way to do it. The problem as stated simply cries out for inheritance, as per Remy Lebeau's answer. (In general: use inheritance when you want the same interface for different behavior, and templates when you want the same behavior for different interfaces.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Polymorphism has some caveat to (it currently doubles the sizeof). `Shape` as-is doesn't had good interface. "Best" depends of context.

Comment: @Jarod42 The biggest caveat of polymorphism is that it often (although not in this case) requires dynamic allocation. On the other hand, it means that the only `if`/`switch` necessary is when creating the object, rather than every time it is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not comfortable with templates yet (as per Jarod42's excellent answer), you might want to simplify your code by breaking "one unit of work" parts into separate functions.

Keeping different levels of abstraction makes it easier to think about each part in isolation, rather than trying to reason about a routine with high complexity.

Simplifying the code this way makes it *longer*, which may seem counterintuitive.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::nan;
using std::runtime_error;
using std::string_view;

#define NAMEOF(x) #x

namespace {

constexpr double π{ 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510 };

auto get_char(istream& = cin) -> char;
auto get_double(istream& = cin) -> double;

struct Shape {
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    double length{nan("")};
    virtual auto prompt() const -> string_view = 0;
    virtual auto area() const -> double = 0;
    friend auto operator>>(istream& in, Shape& s) -> istream& {
        s.length = get_double(in);
        return in;
    }
};

struct Square : Shape {
    auto prompt() const -> string_view override { return "Square length? "; }
    auto area() const -> double override { return length * length; }
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    auto prompt() const -> string_view override { return "Circle radius? "; }
    auto area() const -> double override { return π * length * length; }
};

void InputAndPrint(Shape&& shape) {
    cout << shape.prompt();
    cin >> shape;
    cout << "Area: " << shape.area() << "\n";
}

auto get_char(istream& in) -> char {
    char result;
    if (in >> result) return result;
    throw runtime_error(NAMEOF(get_char));
}

auto get_double(istream& in) -> double {
    double result;
    if (in >> result) return result;
    throw runtime_error(NAMEOF(get_double));
}

} // anon

int main() {
    cout << "Shape type (c/s)? ";
    auto shape_type{ get_char() };

    if (shape_type == 'c') {
        InputAndPrint(Circle{});
    } else if (shape_type == 's') {
        InputAndPrint(Square{});
    } else {
        cout << "Unknown '" << shape_type << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eljiay. Thanks for answer. Why do you use `auto` in `auto shape_type{ get_char()}`  and not `char` ? (Same remarks for `get_double`, ...).

Comment: [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)

Comment: @Stef1611 • use of `auto` for local variables *forces* the programmer (you, me) to initialize the variables immediately, and guides the programmer to define the variable at an appropriate place in the code.

Comment: @Eljay It also obfuscates the code significantly, forcing the reader to figure out the type of the initializing expression. There are times (like iterators in a for loop) where the operations on the type are implicit from the way the type is initialized (e.g. `something.begin()`), and spelling out the type is just extra noise, but they're really the exception.

Comment: @Eljay Hiding information from the reader makes things clearer?

Comment: @So not giving the reader the information immediately, but making him search through additional code, is making things clearer. DRY is an anti-pattern, which generally results in code which is more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @JamesKanze • StackOverflow is not the right venue for this kind of discussion.  Herb Sutter wrote several GotW articles about `auto` and why to use it.

Answer (score -4):

In C++, variable declarations are typically placed at the beginning of a block (e.g., at the start of a function). However, you can still simplify the code and declare variables immediately before they are used. Here's an example:

Copy
using namespace std;

int main() {
// Declare variables near where they are used.

}
In this code, the age and name variables are declared just before they are needed, following the best practice of declaring variables as close as possible to where they are used. This makes the code more readable and concise.

Declaring variables right before they are used is a good practice as it makes it easier to understand the scope and purpose of each variable in your code.

Comment: *"In C++, variable declarations are typically placed at the beginning of a block (e.g., at the start of a function)"* Definitely not. That was a *requirement* in C around 1972 because of limited computer resources.